# Summation of product of combinations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

my question is, can the following series be solved
$$
\sum_{i,j}^{} {a\choose i} {b \choose j}
$$

where, (i+j) mod 3 =0 or i+j is multiple of 3

I need a generalized solution, i.e variables i,j,k... and product terms can range from 1 to 100 say 'm'
and sum of variables (i+j+k+...) is always a multiple of (m+1)

Comment: Welcome to mathSE!. Obvious the sum is restricted to $i\leq a$ and $j\leq b$. Do you have another hypothesis of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Hi, yeah these are the only restrictions apart from i,j>=0

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$ f( x) = \sum_{i,j} { a \choose i } { b \choose j} x ^{i+j}  = ( 1 + x)^a ( 1 + x)^b.$$

Look at $ f( \omega) + f ( \omega^2) + f( \omega^3)$, where $ \omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Recall that $\omega + \omega^2 + 1 = 0$, and that $ \omega^n + \omega^{2n} + 1 = 0 $ if $ n \neq 0 \pmod{3} $ and equals 3 otherwise. Hence,

$$f (\omega ) + f( \omega^2) + f( \omega^3)= \sum _{i,j} {a \choose i } { b \choose i} ( \omega^{i+j} + \omega^{2(i+j)} + \omega^{3(i+j)} ) = \sum_{i+y \equiv 0 \pmod{3} } { a \choose i} { b \choose i } \times 3. $$

This also easily generalizes to having $n$ variables, where we want to ignore those with a sum that are in the same equivalence class modulo $m+1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems correct. Can you help me with the proof why f(w)+f(w^2) = -ans

Comment: I think because he is maybe thinking in the next identity:
$$1+\omega+\omega^2=0$$
but I don't know if he is right

Comment: Incidentally, without restriction on $i$, $j$ this proves Vandermonde's convolution:$$\sum_{i,j} \binom{a}{i} \binom{b}{j} = \sum_{0 \le i \le a} \binom{a}{i} \binom{b}{a - i} = \binom{a + b}{a}$$

Comment: @rlartiga Yes you are. I'd edit the explanation in.